# Maxima of $\sin(nx)/\sin(x)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I was wondering if there is an analytical solution to find the maxima of the following function in terms of $x$:

$$
f(x) = \frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin(x)}
$$

where $n$ is any positive integer greater than $0$

I tried equating the partial derivative of $f(x)$ with respect to $x$ to $0$, but I can't seem to find any other solution than $x = \pi k$ to the resulting trigonometric equation. I was also not able to find a solution in existing posts.

Comment: Are you looking for global maxima or all local maxima?

Comment: Your function is discontinuous for all values of $x=πk$. If you decide to make it into a continuous function by adding the countable infinity of points needed to do so, then you will have a function with an infinity of maxima.

Comment: You should also try to plot this interesting function.

Comment: I should have specified that I'm searching for local maximums, but global maximums are interesting too. ( I'm just intrigued by the function).

Comment: The plot depends greatly on the value of n, by the way. For some values, it reminds me of overlapping and added sinc functions ..

Answer (score 8):

**Hint**
$$
\left|1+e^{i2x}+e^{i4x}+\ldots + e^{i2(n-1)x}\right|= \left|\frac{1-e^{i2nx}}{1-e^{2ix}}\right| = \left|\frac{e^{inx}}{e^{ix}}\frac{\sin (nx)}{\sin(x)}\right|= \left|\frac{\sin (nx)}{\sin(x)}\right|
$$

Also
$$\left|1+e^{i2x}+e^{i4x}+\ldots + e^{i2(n-1)x}\right| \leq \left|1\right|+\left|e^{i2x}\right|+\left|e^{i4x}\right|+\ldots + \left|e^{i2(n-1)x}\right|=n$$
with equality when all terms are real and non-negative.

Comment: [+1] I had completely forgotten this property...

Answer (score 6):

Write $f_n(x) = \dfrac{\sin nx}{\sin x}$. It is familiar from calculus that $\lim_{x \to 0} f_n(x) = n$. If we can prove $|f_n(x)| \le n$ for all $x$ that will imply that $f_n$ has maximum $n$.

Note that if $\sin x = 0$ then $\sin(nx) = 0$ too, so by L'Hospital's rule we find $f_n(x) = \pm n$ (at least in the limit). So assume $\sin x \not= 0$.

In case $n = 2$ we have $f_2(x) = 2 \cos x$ so that $|f_2(x)| \le 2$. Inductively if we assume $|f_k(x)| \le k$ then
$$|f_{k+1}(x)| = \left| \frac{\sin(k+1)x}{\sin x} \right| = \left| \frac{\sin kx \cos x + \cos kx \sin x}{\sin x} \right|\le |f_k(x)||\cos x| + |\cos kx| \le k+1.$$

Thus the global maximum of $f_n$ is $n$.

Comment: [+1] I wouldn't have thought to a proof by recurrence...